# jquery interval loop despite the use of clearInterval

Tags: jquery, loops, setinterval, clearinterval

I am trying to append existing buttons to a new button in a toolbar. I've created code that does this correctly, but it keeps looping despite the interval being cleared.

I've attempted several fixes, mostly to move the `clearInterval()` outside the function (though I've used this structure successfully before) and into a new function in the `try` section. It did not work.

```js
function MoreButton() {
  window.jQuery && (clearInterval(myBrandingInterval), jQuery(window.parent.document).ready(function() {
    var buttons = $(this).find('#MoreButton').data('buttons');
    document.styleSheets[0].cssText = "#cstmItem:hover > #toolbarmorebutton{display:block !important;}#toolbarmorebutton {position:fixed;   background-color:#7D382B;right:0px; }#lnkSignIn,#prefs,#lnkHelp{padding:10px;display:block; }";
    $("#menuList").append("<li id='itemMore' role='menuitem' class='nav-item'><a title='More options' class='link color-s1' id='lnkMore' tabindex='-1' href='#'>More</a><div id='toolbarmorebutton' style='display: none;' title='More'></div></li>");
    if (buttons.includes('Sign In')) {
      $('#lnkSignIn').appendTo($('#toolbarmorebutton'));
    }
    if (buttons.includes('Folder')) {
      $('#itemFolder').appendTo($('#toolbarmorebutton'));
    }
    if (buttons.includes('Preferences')) {
      $('#prefs').appendTo($('#toolbarmorebutton'));
    }
    if (buttons.includes('Language')) {
      $('#itemLanguages').appendTo($('#toolbarmorebutton'));
    }
    if (buttons.includes('Help')) {
      $('#lnkHelp').appendTo($('#toolbarmorebutton'));
    }
  }))
};

try {
  var myBrandingInterval = setInterval("MoreButton()", 500)
} catch (n) {
  console.log(n)
}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(myBrandingInterval)` log?

Comment: You are doing that because you are afraid jQuery is not going to be loaded??

Comment: @epascarello yes. It's a site issue.

Comment: @Thomas I'm not sure I understand what you meant, but I added the line and got this message in the console: [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 48ms

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention you should add it as the first line in the `MoreButton` function. It should output a number or `undefined`.

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio The result is the same I'm afraid.

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio I'm afraid that didn't work other.

Comment: also, the named function should be passed without quotes `setInterval(MoreButton, 500)`

Comment: please refer to this fiddle for a clear example: https://jsfiddle.net/mztv82gq/1/

Comment: By the way, if why not use `setTimeout()'?